# Incorrect number of decimal places on a specific formula

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

I'm having an issue which I can reproduce in three completely unrelated projects in Visual Studio 2010, so I assume this has to do with the .NET framework in general.

When I set a breakpoint in the project, and type in the following text in the following text to be evaluated:

"12500 + 6217.680 + 172.24"

I receive this:

"18889.920000000002"

Note the incorrect number of decimals.

I expect to see this:
"18889.92"

I can type it into a watch window, and it evaluates correctly.  But, not in the Immediate Window.

What gives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is normal behavior for floating point math.  I recommend reading [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

If you want to display this with a specific precision, you should *format* the result using [`value.ToString(format)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kfsatb94.aspx) with a specified amount of precision.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the m suffix to indicate that the numbers are decimals, not doubles, the results will be what you expect (at least in this case).

12500m + 6217.680m + 172.24m = 18889.92